# PHP MYSQL Insert statement in FOR loop Hanging

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have spent many hours debugging, and scouring the internet for a solution to this unusual problem.  Heres the deal:

I am working on a Work Order Submission and Tracking system.  There are two databases involved:

1. The database where the submissions data gets posted, which is located on the same physical machine, but on a separate virtual machine as the webserver serving the php.  They are on the same class C subnet.
2. The database of our tracking system.  Located on a different physical server on a different IP altogether, also a virtual machine.

Our work order system allows for multiple 'services requested', stored in an array.  In our sumbissions database, this is stored as a comma separated string, i.e. "40,60,70" but in our tracking system database, each 'service requested' needs a separate entry, as to allow the different aspects of the project to be tracked and completed at different times, by different staff.

THE PROBLEM IS:  When I place my second insert statement, the one destined for the tracking database, in a for loop, it completely hangs, and takes maybe 5 to 15 minutes, before it passes that point in the code, and sends the confirmation email.  The data does not get inserted either.

When I take it out of the for loop and simply do one insert in the submissions database and one insert into the tracking system, it works fine.

First, Ill post the code that works, but only posts one 'service' to the tracking system:

```
 public function insertOrder()
{
    $services = implode( ',', $this->model->chk );
    $curdate = $this->model->getMySQLDate( $this->model->curdate );
    $dueDate = $this->model->getMySQLDate( $this->model->dueDate );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES(DEFAULT,
            {$this->sanitize($services)},
            {$this->sanitize($curdate)},
            {$this->sanitize($this->model->submittedBy)},
            {$this->sanitize($this->model->shortDesc)},
            {$this->sanitize($this->model->projDetails)},
            {$this->sanitize($dueDate)},
            {$this->sanitize($this->model->dueDateNotes)},
            {$this->sanitize( $this->model->approveBy)},
            {$this->sanitize( $this->model->cost )} )";

    $this->execute( $sql );

    $this->convertServicesToTracks();
    $notes = $this->model->getTracksNotes();
    $dueDate = $dueDate.' 12:00:00';
    $shortDescNoQuotes = str_replace("\"","'",$this->model->shortDesc);

    $sqlTracks = "INSERT INTO todos VALUES(DEFAULT,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($this->model->chk[0])},
            NULL,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($shortDescNoQuotes)},
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($notes)},
            now(),
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($dueDate)},
            NULL,
            12,
            NULL,
            'active',
            NULL,
            now() );";

    //echo $sqlTracks;

    $this->executeTracks( $sqlTacks );
}    private function executeTracks( $sql )
{
    $db = $this->getTracksDB( );


    $this->check4Error( $db, $sql );

    return $result;
}

private function getTracksDB()
{
    if (!$this->tracksdb) $this->tracksdb = new mysqli(AbstractSQL::TRACKS_HOST, AbstractSQL::USER, AbstractSQL::PASS, AbstractSQL::TRACKS_SCHEMA);
    return $this->tracksdb;
}

private function convertServicesToTracks()
{
   //converts submission data to tracking system data
}



private function sanitizeTracks($arg)
{
    if (!isset($arg)) return "NULL";
    if (is_numeric($arg) && !is_double( $arg) ) return $arg;
    return "'{$this->getTracksDB()->escape_string($arg)}'";
}
```

When I add this simple for loop around the second INSERT statement, it hangs, even if the array only has one item!

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->model->chk); ++$i)
    {
        $sqlTracks = "INSERT INTO todos VALUES(DEFAULT,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($this->model->chk[$i])},
            NULL,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($shortDescNoQuotes)},
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($notes)},
            now(),
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($dueDate)},
            NULL,
            12,
            NULL,
            'active',
            NULL,
            now() );";

    //echo $sqlTracks;

    $this->executeTracks( $sqlTacks );
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  And I apologize for the long code snippets!!

Comment: Doing a count() in a loop like that is bad practice. Localize the count first then use that value in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is it iterating through the for loop? I see you have an echo, did that write anything out? How many items does it have to iterate through? 5 min seems like a long time but if there are a lot of items that could be why it's taking so long. Are you seeing any errors in your logs?

Something you might try is hold the count in a variable so it doesn't have to calculate that each time.  It might speed up your for loop but I'm not sure it will insert the data.

```
for($i = 0, $count = count($this->model->chk); $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
        $sqlTracks = "INSERT INTO todos VALUES(DEFAULT,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($this->model->chk[$i])},
            NULL,
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($shortDescNoQuotes)},
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($notes)},
            now(),
            {$this->sanitizeTracks($dueDate)},
            NULL,
            12,
            NULL,
            'active',
            NULL,
            now() );";

    //echo $sqlTracks;

    $this->executeTracks( $sqlTacks );
    }
```

I found this in the PHP for loop reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have this UPDATE:  It may be unrelated to my PHP code!  I just found that the code that worked above yesterday, causes the same hang today.  I think it could be an issue with firewalls and ports on my MYSQL server.  Can anyone advise me to where to look for error logs?  Nothing is appearing in my mysql logs, leading me to believe that the data isn't even getting that far.  But, there are no apache errors either!!  Any ideas??

Comment: I would recommend adding that update to your question so everyone sees it. Assuming your using linux here is an article (not knowing what flavor of linux your running) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/ it might get you close anyway.  Since you've been able to rule out your code you may want to try serverfault.com they might have some insight as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the problem, but shouldn't you generally use a foreach loop to avoid hitting parts of the array that may not exist? There is more about this [here](http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/3/0). If you loop through an empty index, it would break your SQL statement. Like this:

```
foreach($this->model->chk as $val)
```